# Kubernetes Cannot Exec Pod

Tags: kubernetes, containerd

Internal error occurred: error executing command in container: failed to exec in container: failed to start exec "0acebb686c1b464e7219419ce1e15439e28aaaa2ef84392f73ffb077a9cc3c8b": OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "cmd": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iznY.png)

Comment: can you attach the command you have tried?

Comment: Please share some more details. What is the actual scenario and (as already mentioned above) which exact command have you used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think `kubernetes-metrics-scraper` pod has a shell.

It's expected behaviour so it doesn't indicate that there is an issue with it from info that you've provided (if you are accessing to solve something).

You can get more details by checking if pod is in `Running` state, its logs in dashboard or describing a pod.

Some pods can be accessed by passing these commands: `sh`, `/bin/sh`, `bash` or `/bin/bash`, but it's not the case specifically for `kubernetes-metrics-scraper`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think all containers have their own shell

Comment: I had the same issue. `kubectl exec --stdin --tty myPodName -- /bin/bash` did not work. Fortunately `kubectl exec --stdin --tty myPodName -- sh` solved the issue immediately   :D

Comment: for me, it sh with nothing

Answer (score 1):

```
kubectl exec --stdin --tty myPodName -- sh
```

As commented above, it's worked for me.